# Visual Studio 2010 hanging on while debug unit tests with Resharper 8

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

For the first, I want to excuse me for my english.

I've met this problem. My MS Visual Studio 2010 Professional hanging on when I try to run unit tests in debug mode with Resharper 8. My solution contains WCF library prjoect. If I either remove that project or suspend resharper(Tools -> Options -> Resharper ), everything is ok.
   I need resharper to run mspec tests.
Does anybody know how to get rid of this or some workaround?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I had this issue with r# 8 and reverted back to version 7 and everything worked fine.

Comment: I had a similar problem when stopping the tests in debug mode. The behavior is different when stopping the debug-mode and when stopping the running test. When exactly occurs your problem?

Comment: Thank for your answer, Luke 
MichaelS, I haven't even possibility to try to stop in debug. After I press debug, unit tests changes their states to pending and VS doesn't react any more.